# Windows Zend PHP Debugging Environment

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, ioncube

Recent projects (Shopware, xt:Commerce) contain ioncube-encoded files which force me to use the ioncube_loader extension. Loading this along with the ZendDebugger does work unless I try start debugging. Once the loader is included, debugging doesn't work anymore - even in non-encoded environment (for one Joomla).

System: Windows 7, Zend Studio 10.6, Zend Server CE, Zend Debugger, ioncubeLoader, PHP 5.3+

I already spend several days searching for a working solution (except using inline debug commands). If it means, setting up a unix environment, so be it. But there seem to be problems, too.

Windows Event Log shows an Application Error (1000):

```
Faulting application: php-cgi.exe, Version: 5.3.14.0
Faulting module: php5.dll, Version: 5.3.14.0
exception code: 0xc0000005
fault offset: 0x00084494
path to ZendServer php-cgi.exe and php5.dll respectively]
```

Instead of starting a debug session, a download dialog pops up, containg that HTML code

## OK

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additonally, the ZendEnabler.logs shows:

```
[timestamp] Error: Read data error - unable to get read result. Code 109.<br />
[timestamp] Error: Request for D:/Projects/Joomla3/index.php: Unable to get the response from PHP process
```

The joomla folder is mapped to a local virtual host http://joomla3.localhost environment and the subdomain added to the hosts file. No problem if i don't start debugging.

Any help is greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: I recommend testing with xdebug too. Personally I've had so many issues with ZendDebugger so I had to turn to xdebug. Now I'm issue free.

Comment: What are the relevant xdebug lines in your php ini file?

Answer (score 2):

## Just ideas

- This could be something as stupid as a line ending incompatibility.
- Could be a file* permission, php creating files as the wrong user or with wrong privileges.
- Try running the system with elevated permissions? !!Caution, permission elevation is an awful solution.!!
- Could be a Windows shell association, or content type dispatch issue.
- Have you tried reaching out to IonCube's support? They appear to be a commercial product from the top google hit, they should offer support in some manner.
- Try Virtualization? Setup a [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) or other [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and test functionality in there?

Thats all that comes to mind looking at different parts of your problem. :\ Home something helps.

Comment: Woah, has this really been that helpful? can anyone who is marking this as a solution post some specifics on to what the problem is  exactly ans what fixes it Please!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this behavior, correct the DNS address in the Internet Protocol (IP) properties:
Right-click My Network Places, and then click Properties.
Right-click Local Area Connection, and then click Properties.
Click Internet Protocol (TCP/IP), and then click Properties.
Type the correct DNS address in the Preferred DNS server box.

Source:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261007